# Big attachment cause outofmemory Exception in android javamail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail to add mails to Folder in android application.

In this application i am using javamail api from below link
http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

I am using IMAP protocol for this purpose.

Below is my code.

```
     // add atachment
      messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

      DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath()); 

      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

      messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName()); 


      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Then i am using below line to append messages to folder.

```
          try{
                 Log.v(tag, "Sending Mail");    

                 f.appendMessages(msg1);     

                 sucess_flag=1;
                 Log.v(tag, "Mail Send");
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                e.printStackTrace(); 

             }catch(Throwable e)
             {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
             }
```

But i am still getting out of memory exceptions.

I have lsof tried below code but with no success.
       // add atachment
          messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

```
     FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
     DataSource source =new ByteArrayDataSource(fs, mimetype);
      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

      messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName()); 


      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

I thought if i create Inputstream then it will be send in small chunk but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

FileDataSource is the right way to do it, or just use the [attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile%28java.io.File%29) method in [newer versions of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.1_Release).

JavaMail needs to figure out exactly how large the message is before it can append it.  To do that it needs to read all the data for the message.  If the message is small enough, it will cache this data so that it doesn't have to read it again when sending the message.  By default it will try to cache the entire message in memory.  You can set the [mail.imap.appendbuffersize Session property](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) to limit the size of messages that will be cached.

Comment: Hi, I have set property.  
`props.put("mail.imap.appendbuffersize", 8192);`
but same result. i have just downloaded latest version using below link.
https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: Are you using the "imap" protocol or the "imaps" protocol.  If the latter, the property is "mail.imaps.appendbuffersize".  If it still doesn't work, turn on JavaMail Session debugging and post the debug output.

Comment: Hum.. I am using gmail server that is IMAPS i thik.

Comment: Just make sure the property settings are consistent with the protocol you're using.

Comment: hi i have use `props.put("mail.imaps.appendbuffersize", 8192);` but same result.I have donwloaded latest version of java mail.

Comment: Post the debug output when trying to do this, or send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com and I'll help you figure out what's wrong.